# Issue with Timber custom page template for Home page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, templates, timber

I created `page-home-page.twig` in my view folder of Timber template. However,

1- If the page `home-page` set as default wordpress `home-page`, The template file will not work.

2- If the page `home-page` set as normal page content, then now the template will be okay.

Can any one advise me where is the issue?

Please view Timber [documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/custom-page-templates/).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing the following:

**1-** In my WordPress theme folder `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/` I created an **Custom Page Template** reference to this guide: [Custom Page Templates](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/custom-page-templates/)

Using this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Video Template
 * Description: A Page Template for Home page Video CMS.
 */

defined('ABSPATH') or die;
use Timber\Timber;    
$gantry = Gantry\Framework\Gantry::instance();
$theme  = $gantry['theme'];

// We need to render contents of <head> before plugin content gets added.
$context              = Timber::get_context();
$context['page_head'] = $theme->render('partials/page_head.html.twig', $context);
$post                 = Timber::query_post();
$context['post']      = $post;
Timber::render(['page-' . $post->post_name . '.html.twig', 'page-hvideo.twig'], $context);
```

Where `Timber::render(['page-' . $post->post_name . '.html.twig', 'page-hvideo.twig'], $context);` pointing us to the new Timber `page-hvideo.twig` file under **theme/view folder**.

**2-** And in my Timber template view folder I added this file **`page-hvideo.twig`** with the following code:

```
{% extends "partials/page.html.twig" %}
{% set twigTemplate = 'single.html.twig' %}
{% set scope = 'single' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="platform-content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <section class="entry">
                {% include ['partials/content-' ~ scope ~ '-home-video.html.twig', 'partials/content-home-video.html.twig'] %}
            </section>
        </div> <!-- /content-wrapper -->
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Where `{% include ['partials/content-' ~ scope ~ '-home-video.html.twig', 'partials/content-home-video.html.twig'] %}` Will manage the home page custom template from **view/partials** folder under Timber theme folder as normal.

I hope this will help anyone else.

Thank you so much for everything you provided here.

**EDITED:**
Please be sure after you add your Home Page custom page template to select it from your post editing screen in WordPress under **Page Attributes** section.
[image]